# Zend Framework 2 - Integer Form Validation

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2

I've got the following problem. I wrote (based on the tutorial) a form validation. The text fields work just fine but the integer field behave odd.

This is my validator:

```
        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name'     => 'zip',
            'required' => false,
            'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'Int'),
            ),
        )));
```

It lies within my Entity.php like the other filters. The odd thing is that this one accepts not even a string but ignores the `required` when I set it to `true`. I tried to replace `Int` with `Digits` which then causes the form to accept `required` but still accepts strings.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is it a field of type `number` or of type `text`? Considering a text-input will result in a `string` and only a number would send the `integer`, this is where you may have your thought-problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the [Between](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.validator.between.html) validator:

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name'     => 'zip',
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'Int'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
              array(
                  'name' => 'Between',
                  'options' => array(
                      'min' => 1,
                      'max' => 1000,
                  ),
              ),
            ),
        )));
```

Comment: ok, it works. but could you explain why adding an input filter doesn't work?

Comment: ok, i found the solution! the `Int` filter converts non-ints to zero so the database won't fail.

Answer (score 3):

this is a old topic but i should mention that `Filters` don't cause validation errors, they work in background and do their jobs silently .

for example `Int` filter will remove any non-integer from the input , so when you do `$form->getData()` the field with the `Int` filter will only have integer values and 0 if its empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
 array(
                        'name' => 'not_empty',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Digits',
                    ), array(
                        'name' => 'Between',
                        'options' => array(
                            'min' => 0,
                            'max' => 1,
                        ),
                    ),
```