# zf2 doctrine form int required not working

Tags: forms, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, required

```
$inputFilter->add(array(
    'name'     => 'seatingCapacity',
    'required' => TRUE,
    'filters'  => array(
        array('name' => 'Int'),
    ),
));
```

In my Doctrine Entity, I have a `getInputFilter` method which I use for form validation. The above is code snippet for one of the input elements. My problem is the `required => true` is not working even if I submit an empty form.

After researching I found out, that the `Int` filter converts the empty input to `0` and submits it and that is why the `required` validator is not working. I just need reasons why it may not be working.

For reference where I searched

[Zend Framework 2 - Integer Form Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931080/zend-framework-2-integer-form-validation)

where he suggests to use `Between` validator

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
        'name'     => 'zip',
        'required' => true,
        'filters'  => array(
            array('name' => 'Int'),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Between',
                'options' => array(
                    'min' => 1,
                    'max' => 1000,
                )
            )
        )
    )
));
```

I want to know why I should use `Between` and why `required` is failing.

Comment: It feels like you've answered your own question. "...and that is why the 'required' validator is not working"

Comment: I haven't tested the thing (so it's rather a comment than an answer) but can't you use a (combination of) the [to null](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.filter.set.html#tonull) filter, [is int](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.i18n.validator.int.html) validator and [not empty](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.not-empty.html) validator?

Answer (score 0):

You should only use the `Between` validator to validate if the given value is Between a `min` and `max` value. It has nothing to do with solving your empty value to `0` issue.

You should ask yourself 2 questions:

- Is `0` a valid value?
- Do I want to automatically cast `null` empty string (`''`) and other empty values to this `0` or not?

If you actually want to prevent that the `Int` filter sets an empty value to `0`, maybe then you should not use this filter at all then?

You can instead add [an `IsInt` validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.i18n.validators.html#isint) to check if the given value is an integer. Your `required => true` setting will work as expected and validation will fail on any other (not integer) input so also on null, empty strings etc.

Comment: Thank you Wilt. Really appreciate your efforts. Actually I was not getting 'Value required' error message while I should have been worrying if digits are entered or not. And in the course of time I found out 0 should be valid value. So doesn't matter if input is empty but it should not contain anything other than digits. And I met with my requirement as explained .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your time, energy & effort.
Actually I solved the problem.

I had copy-pasted the code, which I should have been careful while doing so.

What I found out is there is no such filter named 'Int' and actually it's 'Digits'

```
$inputFilter->add(array(
'name'     => 'seatingCapacity',
'required' => TRUE,
'filters'  => array(
    array('name' => 'Int'),
),
```

));

shows me error because the filter name should have been 'Digits'.
Only doing so solved my problem and works as per my requirement.

```
$inputFilter->add(array(
'name'     => 'seatingCapacity',
'required' => TRUE,
'filters'  => array(
    array('name' => 'Digits'),
),
```

));

This is the right way to do and I would advice you to be careful while referring code from your sources because it's an illogical mistake I did.

Happy coding